# How to show google.maps.Circle like Marker in Street View mode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I created some `google.maps.Marker` and did bind  `google.maps.Circle` to it (see below):

[image]

But when I open street  view, I see only Marker:

[image]

Does anybody know how to show Circle in street view mode?

Sounds like I can't do that.

Maybe someone knows how to show 2D/3D objects into Google-Street-View.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

This is snippets of code:

```
 var circle = {
        strokeColor: "#006DFC",
        strokeOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#006DFC",
        fillOpacity: 0.15,
        map: mapA,
        center: selectedMarker.getPosition(),
        radius: 50 // in meters

    };
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circle);                 
    cityCircle.bindTo('center', selectedMarker, 'position');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Symbol instead of a `google.maps.Circle` to draw the circle, it will be visible on the panorama.

Getting a 3D-effect would be more complicated, but it should be possible to modify the path of the symbol on the pov_changed-event of the panorama.

Comment: Thank you for answer, As I understand, only Google earth handle 3D objects, maybe I wrong, what do you mean `Symbol`? is it Marker with image?

Comment: It's a marker  defined by a path(via the icon-option of a marker).